# Ошибка при использовании "switch { case __LINE__: ... }"

Tags: c, switch, препроцессор, visual-studio-2022

```
void foo(long i) {
   switch (i) {
      case __LINE__: // <- Ошибка   C2051   значение выражения для варианта выбора не является константой
         break;
   }
}
```

При использовании такой конструкции в "Microsoft Visual Studio Версия 17.7.6" выдаётся ошибка. Файл имеет расширение ".с". Корректна ли выдача такой ошибки? Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 (правда, 17.8.0) — отрабатывает нормально...

Comment: Посмотрите [сюда](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2051?view=msvc-170). Думаю, что тут понятно написано.

Comment: Какую задачу планируется решить?

Comment: Посмотрите, что препроцессор подставил вместо `__LINE__`